# What does independently decodable mean in the context of the OSM PBF Format?

Tags: openstreetmap, pbf

The primitive blocks of the [OSM PBF Format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format) are stated to be independently decodable. What should be the extent of this property?

For example, should all the nodes referenced by a way be stored in the same block or does this property only applies to the string tables, lat/lon offsets and granularity attributes?

Comment: Probably a question for the [OSM-Dev list](https://lists.openstreetmap.org/pipermail/dev/2010-April/019312.html), if the reading of the spec and and practice misalign

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding from reading that:-

> Each fileblock is self-contained, and could be successfully decoded **even if all the other fileblocks disappeared**.

In other words, no entity should be able to refer to an entity in another fileblock. So a relation, its ways, and those ways' nodes would all be in the same block for example. The same goes for any symbols e.g. text fields associated with these entities.

It looks as if Osmosis uses these to create chunks of up to 8000 entities at a time.

That suggests that even if a pbf file was corrupted somehow, the undamaged blocks could still be decoded.

Comment: This is also my understanding and it would be very usefull. However, it is apparently not the case in practice. The existing OSM importers, such as osm2pgsql or imposm3, all seem to create a full node cache before importing ways and relations.

Comment: In its README, imposm3 event states that "it is necessary to store all nodes to build ways and relations ", which seems to contradict the specification of the OSM PBF format.

Comment: The importers take the data out of the PBF and then are free to choose how to generate their structure, is that where you see the nodes before the rest?

Comment: way and relations requiring the nodes does not contradict the idea of storing them closely together in the data format itself.